# SDL2 cannot render entities from vector

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

Rendering individual textures was no problem at all, though after i wrapped these textures in an entity class, and put these in a vector, things just didn't work anymore (renders black screen). Anyone got a clue why?

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "RenderWindow.hpp"
#include "vec.h"
#include "entity.h"

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) > 0) {
        std::cout << "Could not Init VIDEO, Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if (!IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG)) {
        std::cout << "Could not Init IMG, Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    RenderWindow r("Bread.", 600, 600);

    // entity vector
    std::vector<Entity> entities = {Entity(Vec2i{5, 5}, r.CreateTexture("res/gfx/bob.png"))};

    // single entity
    Entity bob(Vec2i{5, 5}, r.CreateTexture("res/gfx/bob.png"));

    bool running = true;
    SDL_Event event;
    while (running) {
        Uint64 start = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                running = false;
            }
        }

        r.Clear();

        // doesn't render (black screen)
        for (const Entity& e : entities) {
            r.RenderEntity(e);
        }

        // renders fine
        r.RenderEntity(bob);

        r.Display();

        Uint64 end = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
        float elapsedMS = (end - start) / (float)SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency() * 1000.0f;
        SDL_Delay(floor(16.666f - elapsedMS));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**RenderWindow.cpp**

```cpp
#include "RenderWindow.hpp"

#include <iostream>


RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const char* p_title, int32_t p_w, int32_t p_h)
    : window(NULL), renderer(NULL) {
    this->window = SDL_CreateWindow(p_title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, p_w, p_h, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (this->window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize window, Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }

    this->renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(this->window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (this->renderer == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize renderer, Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
}

RenderWindow::~RenderWindow() {
    SDL_DestroyWindow(this->window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(this->renderer);
    SDL_Quit();
}

SDL_Texture* RenderWindow::CreateTexture(const char* p_path) {
    return IMG_LoadTexture(this->renderer, p_path);
}

void RenderWindow::Clear() {
    SDL_RenderClear(this->renderer);
}

void RenderWindow::RenderTexture(SDL_Texture* p_texture) {
    SDL_RenderCopy(this->renderer, p_texture, NULL, NULL);
}

// **mentioned method**
// takes const Entity& and renders it's texture
void RenderWindow::RenderEntity(const Entity& p_entity) {
    SDL_RenderCopy(this->renderer, p_entity.GetTexture(), NULL, NULL);
}

void RenderWindow::Display() {
    SDL_RenderPresent(this->renderer);
}
```

and finally **entity.cpp**

```cpp
#include "entity.h"

Entity::Entity(Vec2i p_pos, SDL_Texture* p_texture)
    : pos(p_pos), texture(p_texture) {}

Entity::Entity()
    : pos(Vec2i{0, 0}), texture(NULL) {}

Entity::~Entity() {
    SDL_DestroyTexture(this->texture);
}

void Entity::SetPos(Vec2i p_pos) { this->pos = p_pos; }

const Vec2i& Entity::GetPos() const { return this->pos; }

void Entity::SetTexture(SDL_Texture* p_texture) { this->texture = p_texture; }

// used to get texture of entity to pass to renderer
SDL_Texture* Entity::GetTexture() const { return this->texture; }

void Entity::Move(Vec2i p_pos) {
    this->pos = p_pos;
}

void Entity::Move(size_t p_x, size_t p_y) {
    this->pos.x += p_x;
    this->pos.y += p_y;
}
```

Comment: The Entity destructor is called just before adding to vector, destroying your texture. You create instance of object, next default copy constructor is called, and then finally the original one is destructed.  You should manage lifetime of texture in another way or keep vector of (smart)pointers to your Entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creation of `entities` requires a temporary `Entity`, which is destroyed afterwards. Since you did not implement a copy constructor, this leaves the new Entity with a dangling pointer to a freed object.

The quickest fix is to change the type of `Entity::texture` to `std::shared_ptr<SDL_Texture>`.

Alternatively, you can create a move constructor and prevent copy constructors:

```
Entity::Entity(const Entity&) = delete;
Entity::Entity(Entity&& other)
  : pos(other.pos), texture(nullptr) {
  std::swap(texture, other.texture);
}
```